# What should I basically expect from access to an OpenVZ based VPS?

Tags: linux, virtualization, openvz

I'm going to buy access to an [OpenVZ](http://openvz.org/Main_Page) based VPS for the first time. I want to run common software, like apache, irc server, znc, a mail server etc. I'd like to get an idea of how the system will be setup initially? Am I given ssh access or some other remote access facilities? Is it a pre-configured minimal system? What else should I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on the provider.  Usually you are given a basically fresh installation of which ever distro you choose.  The provider will usually let you choose your root password and give you SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pretty much any other linux system.

The two main differences:

- You have no control over the kernel. The kernel will be whatever the host system is running. You can install other kernels, but it's effectively impossible to boot from them.
- You don't have full control over your network. The network will probably be configured by the provider. You can pretty much ignore it. If you need any networking changes you'll probably need to contact the provider.

Security considerations:

From the host side (i.e., the provider) all files on the guest (i.e., you) are accessible and readable. They're part of the host's filesystem. So private keys aren't really private. Likewise the contents of RAM can be read because it's allocated space in the host's RAM.

Treat everything you do as though an unknown and untrusted stranger is watching everything you do and makes a copy of every file (if the provider makes back ups, this will be true). I'm not saying don't use encryption. You can still be secured against third-party snoops. But be aware that there is no secrecy from your provider, and they can disclose information to others. Your data is only as safe as the least scrupulous employee of your provider.